# [MongoDB]:where is the incoming write operations saved in when the balancer is doing migration?

Tags: mongodb

please see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-internals/#balancing-internals.

it has the following phrase:

"when MongoDB begins migrating a chunk, the database begins copying the data to the new server and tracks incoming write operations."

my question is where is these incoming write operations saved in? if it is in memory,then i need how to call getLastError and ensure the data has been synchronous to disk. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to guarantee a write, you should be calling getLastError (or using your driver's equivalent for a safe write) anyway, regardless of whether you are using sharding or not.

In terms of what happens to operations during a migration.  You can find the answers to what happens to the data for in-flight writes by looking at the answer to these two questions in the FAQ:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#what-happens-if-a-client-updates-a-document-in-a-chunk-during-a-migration

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#what-does-writebacklisten-in-the-log-mean

The two mechanisms describe what happens, depending on the nature of the operation.  Either the origin shard for the migration ensures that the writes are "sent on" to the destination shard, or the writeback mechanism sends them back to the mongos process (where they will be automatically retried).

Comment: Thanks Adam! In fact I want to know how MongoDB deal with these incoming write operations? current chunk is migrating, how to save these affected data?

Comment: As I said it saves them to the source shard of the chunk that is being migrated (assuming the writes are in that chunk), then it will send those writes on to the target shard before the end of the migration, so that they end up on the correct shard.  Anything in-flight is sent back to the mongos and the operation is retried once the mongos has refreshed its view of the chunks and knows to send the operations to the target shard.

Comment: Yes，I see, it saves them to the source shard, but I want to know more detailed. which chunk? this chunk is being migrated, can it be changed?

Comment: A chunk is just a description of a group of documents (meta data) - it is not physical.  One shard sends documents, based on that description to the other shard.  If you are writing to that group of documents (updates) or adding to that range (new docs), then those changes/additions are what is sent on by the source shard when the chunk is migrated.  If you are not writing to that chunk, the it is business as usual.  This is being done to keep your data balanced across the shards - why are you looking to change it?